# Why is there a huge 'data' file in the root of my ES coordinating node install directory?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.8

Was troubleshooting an slowness/crashing issue when I noticed that my C drive filled up with a 32GB 'data' file without any file extension. My best guess is that it's a heap dump file, but the name and the file extension (or lack there of) don't match. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey StuporScooper, How many RAM does this system have? You can configure jvm.options to write heap dumps / logs to a separate disk. At least that way you don't risk filling up your os disk. Also are there any elasticsearch cluster logs around the time this data file was created?

Comment: The system has 128GB with just under 32GB given to the coordinating node. The logs from the rest of the cluster were only spot checked but didn’t see anything that stood out.